# PHP variable inside ssh2_exec

Tags: php, linux, phpseclib, ps, ssh2

**OS: Ubuntu 16.04**

I tried to use variable inside ssh2_exec but I get this message:

```
PID TTY TIME CMD 12585 pts/0 05:27:05 samp03svr bash: line 1: -o: command not found
```

My code:

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$cmd = "sudo ps -p {$user->sshConnect()} -o %cpu";

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('IP');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec($cmd);
```

sshConnect function:

```
public function sshConnect(){
    $connection = ssh2_connect('IP', 22);
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'lsof -t -i :6000');

    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    $out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
    return stream_get_contents($out);
  }
```

But, if I replace {$user->sshConnect()} with my current PID, it works fine.
Also $user->sshConnect(), return valid PID when I echo it.

Thanks.

Comment: It's kinda strange that you're using two different SSH libraries. I'd use one or the other - not both. Regardless...  what do you get when you echo out `$cmd`?

Comment: I'm solved this by adding preg_replace. Because sshConnect was retrieve info with whitespace. Now works fine.